# LuaLaTeX + load one particular math symbol from an OTF file

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode-math

I try to load exactly one symbol from an OpenType Font file and use it in a math environment. However, it seems to me, that I can only use the symbol in "normal" text but not in math mode. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newfontfamily\foo{Untitled1.otf}

\newcommand{\foobar}{\foo\symbol{1}}

\begin{document}
\foobar
\[x \foobar y\]
\end{document}
```

In normal text the symbol appears but in math mode it does not. Do I have to use some special command to load a symbol for a math environment?

Or the other way arround. How could I typeset a formula where the first part of the formula is typed in font A and the second part in font B (where A != B)?

**Update**

The question aims at the following problem. I created a new symbol which is not known to be available in Unicode. Therefore I created a new one and saved in the file Untitled1.otf. Now I want to load this symbol into my document and use it in math formulas. Since the symbol is not known in unicode I cannot use a "standard" symbol to refer to it. Therefore, I thought to use a command and reference the symbol by its index of the OTF file.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a PDF with the symbol and say something like `\newcommand{\foobar}{\includegraphics{mysymbol}}`?

Answer (score 4):

Just for one symbol, it's probably not worth going through the math setup, just define it as

```
\newcommand{\foobar}{\text{\foo\symbol{1}}}
```

so it'll work in math mode using the text font setup. (If you need it to get smaller in subscripts, load `amsmath` which will define `\text` to do that).

Answer (score 3):

in this example the first 1 is taken from Latin modern math and all the other from XITS Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
{\setmathfont[range="0031]{Latin Modern Math}
\[x 1 y\] }
\[x 1 y\]
\end{document}
```

another example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont[version=XITS]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=LMM]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{XITS}
\[x \mbox{\mathversion{LMM}$1$} y\] 
\[x 1 y\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But how do you then typeset a formula where you want the number 1 typeset one time in Latin Modern Math and the other time in XITS Math? My question aims at the following problem. I created a new symbol which I then want to load into my document. Since this is not a standard/known symbol I cannot refer to it via a standard/printable symbol. I will update my question regarding this information.

Comment: see edit of my answer

Comment: But then I cannot typeset `$1 1$` anymore where the first one is typeset in Latin Modern and the second one is typeset in XITS. Again this all goes back to the problem that I want to define a new operator symbol such that I can write `a \fancynewop b` where `\fancynewop` should be a symbol out of an OTF file Untitled1.otf.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't see why you want the same symbol to be taken from different fonts in the same formula, why don't you give your new symbol a unique code point in the private use area and simplify the issue.

Comment: @Stefan: see 2nd example in my answer

Comment: @KhaledHosny: The problem is that I would like to create a package that all colleagues can use. Unicode supports PUAs but they do not have a concept like name spaces. Therefore, uniqueness cannot be assured. @Herbert: The `\mbox`-solution is nice but it has one drawback. If used in subscript mode, then the symbol is not loaded properly, i.e. it is loaded for "normal" mode but not for subscript mode.

Comment: @Stefan: then use `\text` from `amsmath` instead

Comment: @Herbert: But `\text` has the drawback that not the subscript version from the OTF file is used, instead the symbol is only scaled down.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: After hours of searching, trying and hacking I'm inclined to the PUA-solution you have mentioned. I've tried to come up with a solution but frankly I failed. Can you elaborate how to load some parts from an OTF file. I tried it with `\setmathfont[range={"0041-"0042}]{XITS Math}` but any capital A is still typeset in Latin Modern Math, not XITS Math.

Comment: @Stefan: then define the font attribute for subscript ...